# $A\in M_n$ is nonzero and nonnegative , $A$ has a positive eigenvector $\mathop \Rightarrow \limits^? $ $\rho (A) > 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Suppose that $A\in  M_n$ is  nonzero and nonnegative (i.e: all $a_{ij}\ge 0$) .

If $A$ has a positive eigenvector (i.e :all $x_i>0$), Why does $\rho (A) > 0$?

(Note: $\rho (A) = \max \left\{ {\left| \lambda  \right|:\lambda  \in \sigma (A)} \right\}$ where ${\sigma (A)}$ be spectrum of $A$.)

Comment: What do you mean by "positive eigenvector"?

Comment: @Nitrogen - i.e :all $x_i>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is non negative and $x$ is positive, then also $Ax$ is non-negative. 
Moreover $Ax \neq 0$, since $A\neq 0$ and $x>0$ (i.e. there exist $a_{ij}>0$, and then $(Ax)_{i}>0$.

Then
$$Ax=\lambda x \mbox{ non negative and } \neq 0,\: x>0 \;\Rightarrow \lambda >0$$
and so
$$\rho(A)\geq |\lambda|=\lambda>0$$